# .NET 2.0 Assembly and .NET 3.0 Assembly

Tags: .net

I have an old project that was build on VS 2008 .NET 2.0. The project is running fine. We upgraded the project on dev side to VS 2010 .NET 3.0. Now, my question is that if I upload the new 3.0 assemblies on the production will it work. Will some .NET 2.0 assemblies be able to communicate with the .NET 3.0 assembly? Our push to production is a simply DLL (3.0) push and on production most of the assemblies are .NET 2.0.

I think it should work since .NEt 2.0 and .NEt 3.0 share the same codebase. If it was .NET 4.0 then it would be totally different.

Comment: do you have the 3.0 framework installed in the production environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. They will work together: .net 3.0 = .net 2.0 + WCF+WPF+WF

Comment: To put it another way: .NET 3.0 isn't a framework; it's just .NET 2.0 with some added DLLs.

Answer (score 1):

.NET assemblies can call .NET assemblies which where targeted to older frameworks without problems.

Additionally make sure that all your clients have .NET framework 3.x installed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is no difference in the runtime between v2.0 and v3.0, or v3.5 for that matter (not counting service packs).  v3.0/3.5 were just additional libraries added to the v2.0 runtime, but under the hood it's till v2.0.