# Compiling .NET 3.0 DLL into .NET 2.0 assembly in VS2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, .net-2.0

I'm trying to upgrade a project which currently exists in Visual Studio 2005/.NET 2.0 to work with Visual Studio 2010.  This would be easy if I could bump the .NET version, but for now it **must** remain a .NET 2.0 application.  Again, this would be relatively easy, except the VS2005 project is referencing some .NET 3.0 DLLs, such as System.ServiceModel.

This referencing of a .NET 3.0 dll works just fine in VS2005, since (as [this answer says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4155344/298754): `.net 3.0 = .net 2.0 + WCF+WPF+WF`).  However, I can't figure out how to teach VS2010 that this is a working combination.

*Specifically*, the .NET 3.0 assemblies don't show up in the dialog for adding references, and manually adding them (via "Browse"), while it lets *that* project build correctly, keeps that project from being referenced by any other.  When I try to build a dependent project, it generates an error: `warning MSB3268: The primary reference "{{MyProject}}.dll" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v2.0".`

**How can I reproduce VS2005's *laissez faire* attitude towards combining .NET 2.0 and .NET 3.0 in VS2010?**

Comment: As an aside: If the answer is "You can't", I will be very sad.  I *really* like my 2010 extensions.

Comment: That warning was specifically designed to alert you that your program will never run on a .NET 2.0 install.  Wishing it away is rather silly.  Otherwise a strong hint that your target selection is drastically out of step with what your customers are actually running.  Which is accurate, pretty hard to find users that choose to get stuck on a 9 year old version of free software :)

Comment: @HansPassant - A) Why does VS2005 not complain?  B) The lack of ability to upgrade is based on the lack of bandwith to do the extensive regression testing necessary to insure that everything still works exactly the same. I know it *should*, but you know what they say about the difference between theory and practice...

Comment: VS2005 doesn't know beans about .NET 3.0, it can't complain about something it doesn't know exist.

Comment: @HansPassant - I guess that makes sense... but then how can it work with the 3.0 assembly if it doesn't know that it can exist?  Will our software work on a system which strictly only supports 2.0, or does everything have to have 3.x installed too (I haven't tried)?

Comment: That warning was specifically designed to alert you that your program will never run on a .NET 2.0 install.  I'm repeating myself, can't guess why this is not completely obvious.

Comment: @HansPassant - I feel like we're going in circles.  You're saying VS2005 doesn't know about 3.0, which means the DLL has to be backwards compatible enough for VS2005 to understand it, but you're also saying that it isn't backwards compatible to a .NET 2.0 install.

Comment: There is nothing particularly special about a 3.0 assembly, it still uses the v2.0.50727 version of the CLR.  The only detail is that a machine that has .NET 2.0 installed is not going to have that assembly available.  So the program will not run.

Comment: @HansPassant - *Ah!* It makes sense now... So shouldn't I be able to resolve my error by setting "Copy local" on the reference to `true`?

Comment: If you are looking to ignore the indirect dependency warning you might try adding <SpecificVersion>True</SpecificVersion> to the MyProject.dll reference in the project file of your other projects. Unless you have a very good reason for it though, you might be asking for trouble.

Comment: @HansPassant - As it happened, I got permission to just upgrade the relevant projects to 3.0 and kill the warning that way. If you want to put in an answer saying that it works in VS2005 because X, and I can't suppress it because Y, I'll accept it.  Otherwise, I'll self-answer some time next week.